# Is there a huge difference between 2D and 3D colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a 3D game that uses only two axes gameplay-wise. The player may move up and down, left and right but not anywhere else.

Up until this point I still used 3D colliders - boxes and spheres. But when profiling the game, I found out that physics take a huge chunk of CPU processing power for a game that has one dynamic and multiple static colliders.

My first idea was recoding the whole game and all of its physics in order to have 2D colliders. That will take some time, and I am still not sure if it's worth it. Is there a difference for Unity between processing 100 box colliders and 100 box colliders 2D? Or 100 spheres and 100 circles? I really wanna know if it's worth it before doing so.

Comment: Yes there is a huge difference and will definitely be worth it if you can do it